# VBA copying and pasting from different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from `column B` in the `Resource` worksheet to the `TEST` worksheet.

It´s meant to copy from `B7` onwards and I wanted it so that it searched the last row in the `TEST` one and paste it there using `Offset (1,0)` but it doesn't seem to work as I had hoped.

```
 Sub CopyName()
 Worksheets("TEST").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = 
 Worksheets("Resource").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value
 End Sub
```

Comment: You never mention to start at B7

Comment: Do you want the data “pasted” to also start on Row 7?

Comment: What does it do different from your expectations? In my test, it works as described. It takes the last value in column B on the Resource sheet and puts it into the next empty cell in column B on the TEST sheet. What do you want done differently? What had you hoped?

Comment: sorry was error on post. updated and working fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will

1. Grab range from `Resource` starting from `B7` down to the last used row in `Column B`
2. Move the range to `Test` on first available non-blank cell

---

```
Sub CopyName()

Dim Resource As Worksheet: Set Resource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resource")
Dim Test As Worksheet: Set Test = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST")
Dim ResourceRange As Range

Set ResourceRange = Resource.Range("B7:B" & Resource.Range("B" & Resource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Test.Range("B" & Test.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(ResourceRange.Rows.Count, 1).Value = ResourceRange.Value

End Sub
```